How did the rebels take over al-Assad's regime in Syria so quickly?
Rebel groups took over al-Assad's 53-year-old regime in Syria in about 10 days since they first started their offensive in Aleppo. How did they manage to do that so quickly?

The forces defending a regime need the capability to resist and the will to resist.
The capability can be counted in battalions, in battleships, in jet fighters. Measuring it is relatively easy, even if there are endless debates between experts and even more endless debates between armchair experts on just how much better this or that piece of equipment is. Look at the websites trying to count how many tanks Russia lost in Ukraine. Training is also a factor here, and hard to estimate.
The will to resist is much harder to measure, and it can change very rapidly. If you look at the end of the Second World War, the German troops were quite willing to resist the Soviets, motivated by their knowledge of German atrocities in the East and their fear of reprisals. On the western front, they were much more willing to surrender in the last weeks, where the same unit had fought tenaciously just days before.
The troops on both sides will compare their personal prospects if they fight or if they surrender. Few are fanatic enough to become the last casualties of a lost cause. Those prospects depend on the overall political and military situation, and also on what the soldier in the foxhole next to them is doing. The result can be a rapid "domino effect."
In particular, note that Prime Minister al-Jalali is either trying to strike a deal, or has actually done so. That is a blow to the morale of the troops.
Jonathan asked in a comment what made them collapse now, not earlier. user13964273 pointed out that HTS is much better equipped. But that is not the decisive factor. Syrian rebels had Western support a decade ago, too. Russian support for Assad used to be more effective. Again, that is not the decisive factor. It is a psychological thing. When the HTS had enough momentum, enough regime loyalists defected to start an avalanche.

The question is what changed between now and 12 years ago when the whole thing started. Assad's control over Syria has been on the verge of collapse several times, what changed now?

@JonathanReez, my understanding is that small changes of momentum added up. Yes, they were on the brink before. But this time they got so close to the brink that people like al-Jalali thought they should jump the sinking ship. Trying to pin the start of that avalance to a specific event would be blind guessing.

This entire answer contains zero cited sources or anything specific at all about Syria.

The answer even says measuring the capabilities of an army is relatively easy, and then provides no info about Syria's army. It strikes me as lazy answering without any fact finding.

@qwr, I was saying that counting tanks and howitzers is relatively easy, and often not indicative of the outcome of the battle. That makes the count pointless in a case like this, where the defender "unraveled" in many areas without a fight.

You'll have to wait for some better history of this to be written, especially for the crucial days of 5-7 December in the south. While there were foreign journalists (from Arabic language countries) embedded with the HTS and so their exploits have been well documented, the uprising in the south has had little detail in the press till now.
And it's the southern rebels that reached Damascus first. HTS was only just arriving on Dec 8 and they've announced a curfew, probably in an attempt to establish their control over the capital.
But what we do know: Assad's forces were unable to stop HTS in Hama. (Russian air support has also been evidently insufficient, e.g. it failed to cut the crucial bridge between Hama and Homs.) And after that Assad started to pull forces from other regions to bolster that front as the battle of Homs was progressing. This was most evident in Deir ez-Zur, which was passed over to the Kurds (SDF).
It's far less clear what happened in the south but many localities there were taken over by the southern revolutionaries without a fight. It looks like most if not all the rebel fighters that have reached Damascus for now are from Daraa (and Damascus itself). And the PM has been meeting with them, making some transition deal.
So it was partly a collapse of the overstretched hardcore military (and this was also due to reduced foreign support with Hezbollah busy in Lebanon, Russia in Ukraine  etc.), and looks like at least partly the more moderate regime elements making deals with the less islamist opposition in previously 'pacified' areas like the south. The PM by the way has called for free elections now. That will perhaps not sit well with HTS, which wants an islamic state (and held no elections in their stronghold of Idlib that they've controlled for years.)
Dec 10 addition:

Prime Minister Mohammed al-Jalali told Saudi TV channel al-Arabiya he had agreed to hand over power to the rebel Salvation Government.

The latter refers to the HTS-backed government that ran only Idlib till now. No more mention of elections.

If you want to roll back the clock/question to how the HTS was able to get the ball rolling and capture Aleppo so quickly... that's also not entirely clear to me. But some elements that we do know of is that HTS managed to organize itself to include a drone unit (that showed footage of hits on armor and fixed positions) and they've clearly expanded their own fleet of armored vehicles. Alas mostly footage from the rebels has been available on (Western) social media, so it surely has some selection bias, but what it showed was sometimes shocking like the rebels using tanks and IFVs (albeit old BMP-1s) to run over part of Assad's force that apparently lacked any armor (at least in that footage posted) and relied on light vehicles ('technicals'); pretty much an inversion of roles. Before such scenes, the highways were littered with tanks apparently abandoned by Assad's forces, including fairly new tanks like T-90s, apparently intact. Exactly why isn't clear to me.

HTS have also said they want elections in their public statements, and said they want a diverse Syria. That may be lip service of course.

And an agreement between say Israel and Turkey partitioning up Syria for their own gain would not be made public. Nor would other interests regarding pipelines and whomever will profit from that. One thing for certain, Syrians will not be better off, same as Libya.

If someone wants the Russian perspective (as summarized/translated by the BBC correspondent) https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tUMGkQZS4rc Among other things, they blame Assad's regime for surrendering cities whitout a fight.

@JackAidley: "HTS have also said they want elections". I didn't see that.

Thanks, FYI the question got closed, reopen vote welcome if you think it's on topic.

There was a TV report stating that many of the abandoned, undestroyed tanks and other military vehicles were left because of lack of fuel supplies. The Syrian army seemed to be in a similar state as 10 years ago in the fights against FSA, ISIS and other groups: disorganized, corrupted, incapable. In Iraq, many soldiers did only exist in the official military lists - the "soldiers" could stay at home and would share their income with the commanders. Maybe in Syria similar things happened right now - f.e. selling the military gasoline and ammunition/weapons on the black market etc.

No one expected this to happen  so quick but in essence Syria under Assad was not a country capable of  or expecting to defend itself with its own forces since the original Syrian civil war. It relied on protection from Iran, Russia and Hezbollah. All three of them immediately  abandoned Assad when this round of fighting started.  So did many of his own army officers. Even in Assad's own palace where you would expect the most loyal of all his guards to be stationed, the footage of the rebels taking it over shows zero resistance. The guards just ran away rather than confront the rebels. As such who and  what was left to protect the Assad regime?
As of this writing, opposition fighters still did not enter Lattakia and Tartous, coastal territories  – that are Assad strongholds. They are obviously avoiding  fighting in places where they will face serious resistance. So in essence this really boils down to Assad falling immediately because there was no one who wanted to defend his regime.  When only one side is willing to fight they will achieve victory very quickly.

This NPR interview from Sunday morning (audio only, for now) roughly says that, if you want to add a source. An ex-Syrian captive says Russia completely propped up Assad in 2016 (air&ground), Iran was unable to help this time, and re: no one defending he says the rebels made a point of being very nice to minorities: https://www.npr.org/2024/12/08/nx-s1-5220346/after-the-fall-of-assad-what-comes-next-for-syria

The loyal guards might have "ran away", or they might have traveled together with Assad to protect him in exile.  A bit premature to assume desertion/cowardice.

It's quite simple: Assad was kept in power only by Iranian and Russian support. That support was eroded in the former case by Israel's decimation of Iranian terror proxies (Hamas, Hezbollah), and in the latter case by the continuing single-minded determination of Russia to waste forces in the meat-grinder that is Ukraine. HTS simply took advantage of this vacuum of external support to launch a decisive attack on the Syrian loyalist forces.
In short, this is not so much a win by HTS's military prowess, as it is a loss by Assad's tired, depleted and dispirited forces.

What about reports that Syria's army has been underfunded and plagued with corruption?

The Syrian civil war has now been going on for 13 years after the initial discontent with the regime surfaced in 2011 which rapidly turned into an insurgency. By the following year the insurgency had become a full scale civil war.
The rebel forces, equipped by NATO and some Arab countries initially made significant inroads into Assad's regime. This then catapulted Assad's allies Iran and Russia into the fray in order to defend Assad which decisively turned the tide of the battle in favour of the government forces. Russian forces were bolstered by the Wagner group and Iran deployed its proxy, Hezbollah, into Syria.
However, on the most recent offensive into Aleppo and then Damascus, Assad's forces weren't backed by either Russia or Iran. This is mostly due to Russia's military being tied up with the Ukraine war and Iran's proxy, Hezbollah, being greatly diminished by Israel. Also, its important to count in the demoralisation of the government forces in fighting a civil war. It seems from various reports that Damascus was hardly defended when the rebels advanced. And so the city was quickly taken.

That's a fascinating question, easy enough to answer in hindsight - once it happened.  But let no one tell you it was preordained.
It wasn't expected to happen, apparently.
Omranstudies.org

Although the stated objective of the operation was to counter further escalation by the regime and Russia, following intensified airstrikes and bombardment on Northern Syria, the poor performance of regime forces allowed the HTS and the opposition to achieve significant and unexpected advances.


The objective of the operation was set to be limited, yet the collapse of the regime’s defenses has allowed the armed alliance to advance unexpectedly fast, shocking Syrians as well as the experts who have been analyzing the Syrian conflict for more than a decade.

Supposedly, the starting goal of the Aleppo push was to push out Syrian government forces from elevated positions overlooking the city, which they used to direct artillery strikes against Aleppo.
Stuff happens - armies fight on morale and cohesion, possibly more than materiel and numbers.
No one wants to be the last to die for a lost cause.  We've seen this play out in Afghanistan in 2021.  Armies that look strong on paper (i.e. not the Syrian Army) can evaporate on the battlefield in an ever-snowballing effect. Even if you and your unit would be ready to fight, when you come to believe your fellows and nearby units literally don't have your back, there is a strong incentive to cut and run.  There are a number of specialized military terms for that: rout, collapse, loss of cohesion and things can move very quickly.  This is certainly what happened in Syria.
Omranstudies:

Alongside the capture of Aleppo, the armed alliance has taken control of the southern countryside of Idlib and the city of Hama, where the regime had reorganized its groups and brought reinforcement to stop the collapse of its defense lines, yet to no avail.

Reuters

Twenty-three-year-old Syrian military conscript Farhan al-Khouli was badly paid and demoralized. His army outpost in scrubland near the rebel-held city of Idlib should have had nine soldiers but it just had three, after some had bribed the commanding officers to escape serving, he said.  And, of the two conscripts with him, one was regarded by his superiors as mentally unfit and not trusted with a gun, Khouli said.


Khouli put his phone on airplane mode, changed into civilian clothes, dropped his rifle and fled. As he walked along the road back south, other groups of soldiers were abandoning their posts too.

France 24

The Britain-based Syrian Observatory for Human Rights, a war monitor, reported soldiers repeatedly evacuating positions across the country as the insurgents pushed forward, seizing one city after another.


Syrian insurgents toppled President Bashar al-Assad's on Sunday after a stunning, two-week offensive that saw major cities slip from the regime’s fingers one by one, until rebel forces captured the capital Damascus almost without a fight.


Opposition forces entered the capital with little or no resistance on Sunday as the Syrian army melted away

Al Jazeera

Soldiers and police officers were reportedly abandoning their posts, handing over their weapons, and fleeing ahead of the opposition advance.


The rebels advanced quickly – within days, they took Hama and Homs, a city once dubbed “Capital of the Revolution” during the early years of the war.


On Saturday, Deraa – the birthplace of the 2011 uprising – also slipped from government control.


The Syrian army announced it was “redeploying and repositioning” in the province and nearby Sweida, but that seemed to come to nought.

ISW Dec6

The Bashar al Assad regime faces an existential threat given the widespread collapse of regime forces and lack of sufficient external backing to bolster these forces. Various Syrian groups opposed to Assad, including local opposition in southwestern Syria, the US-backed Syrian Democratic Forces (SDF), and the Hayat Tahrir al Sham (HTS)-led Fateh Mubin Operations Room, have each rapidly seized territory across Syria in the past 24 hours as Assad regime forces have collapsed. Assad’s backers do not appear willing to bolster the Syrian Arab Army by rapidly deploying additional forces. One source “close to the Kremlin,” for example, told Bloomberg that unless Assad’s forces manage to form a defensive line—a scenario that is becoming increasingly less likely as more and more Syrian regime units break—Russia will not “save” Assad.1

People have already talked about the absence of Russia, Hezbollah and Iran.  This was critical and this is was made this operation so well-timed.  But it wasn't a foregone conclusion, not like many now seem keen to explain.
Could have been very different
Had the Idlib/Aleppo initial operation encountered reasonable opposition from the Syrian Army, had the Syrian Army managed to stiffen around Hama and Homs, then things could have played out very differently.  A few good local commanders, some more motivated units in the beginning would have avoided the sense of inevitability that triggers military collapses.
That's what makes these things hard to predict, though a less incompetent government in Syria might have seen the risks of it happening.  Just like it "was written" that Russia would easily take over Ukraine.  Until it didn't in the first week or two and the reverse, equally unpredictable, phenomenon developed.
By the time Homs was taken, it was too late as the regime was now cut off from coastal Alawite and Russian support
What were regime risk factors?
Lots and lots of corruption, resentment and incompetence.  And those pesky missing Russians and Hezbollahs.
Reuters:

Many midranking officers had been growing increasingly angry in recent years that the army's sacrifices and successes during the war were not reflected in better pay, conditions and resources, two serving, one recently retired and one defected officer said.


Crucially, much of the Syrian military's operational command structure was run by Iranian military advisors and their militia allies, they said.


As Aleppo came under attack in late November, army units were not given a clear plan but were told to work it out for themselves or to fall back to the strategic city of Homs to try to regroup, two Syrian security sources said.

France 24:

Assad's army has been reduced to little more than a hollow shell after a 14-war war that killed more than half a million people, displaced half of Syria’s prewar population of 23 million, and devastated the country's economy and infrastructure.


In the war's early years, experts said a combination of casualties, defections and draft-dodging saw the military lose around half of its 300,000-strong force. Corrupt and demoralised, the army was caught unawares when rebels suddenly burst out of their redoubt in Idlib province on November 27, meeting little resistance.


"Since 2011, Syria's army has faced attrition in manpower, equipment and morale," said David Rigoulet-Roze, a Syria expert at the French Institute for International and Strategic Affairs. Underpaid soldiers reportedly looted resources to survive, and many young men evaded conscription, he told AFP.


On Wednesday, Assad ordered a 50 percent raise in career soldiers' pay in a desperate effort to bolster his crumbling army. But with Syria's economy in tatters, soldiers' salaries are almost worthless and the move had little impact.

Al Jazeera:

Syria was struggling as its economy tanked, reportedly propped up largely by an illicit trade in the psychoactive drug Captagon.


Al-Assad became hugely unpopular as people found it harder and harder to survive, including his soldiers, the majority of whom did not want to fight for him.

Omranstudies:

On the other hand, the regime’s institutions were grappling with severe challenges. Anonymous attacks have targeted highly securitized areas in Damascus, its outskirts, Homs, and Quneitra undermining the regime’s control in these regions (14). Additionally, the continuous targeting of regime locations by the IDF has also played a significant role in weakening its forces. The regime’s involvement in the Captagon industry and trafficking has also affected its military structure, occasionally resulting in infighting among various official and auxiliary forces (15).

We also need to remember that the Syrian Army had been losing the war at the outset in 2011 and were only stabilized with Russian and Hezbollah help (Russia in the air, Hezbollah to fight on the ground).
Conscription in Syria is very onerous, long and open-ended (you are always in the reserves).  It can also be opted out, at a cost, if you are abroad.  And there is a corrupt system to sell exemptions.

In war-torn Syria, Bashar Al-Assad’s regime has exploited conscription to control the society and extract financial resources. This further impoverishes the society while favoring corruption and the president’s centralization efforts.

What were rebel success factors?
Omranstudies

resentment and grievances among locals, particularly IDPs living in makeshift camps, was reinforced. UNHCR estimates the numbers of the internally displaced persons in Northwestern Syria to be close to 3.6 million out of 5 million, 1.9 million of whom have been living in camps and self-settled sites (5). For years, many displaced young men, and even elderly men, have been balancing work with intermittent military training. This reality illustrates why the HTS and the armed opposition set the objective of the operation as facilitating the return of displaced people to their original cities and towns(6).


HTS has been transforming itself into a hybrid actor by modifying insurgent tactics and claiming conventional army principles simultaneously. First, HTS has transformed its insurgent tactics, most importantly, developing its drone capabilities, which seem indispensable for the current battle. Before the current use of drones, HTS’s drone attacks have reportedly reached the Russian Khmeimim Air Base in Latakia(9) and the regime's stronghold al-Qardaha (10) among dozens of other locations in 2023.


Second, HTS began adopting functions traditionally reserved for conventional armies, including the establishment of a military academy, a military training department, a conscription office, and a center for military studies and planning. The group has benefited from former Syrian military commanders who defected from the regime during the war; their expertise was invaluable for HTS in restructuring its armed wing and building institutions. The head of HTS, al-Jawlani, even expressed intentions to establish a defense ministry and “get out of the factionalism situation (11)"


Other reasons also explain the impressive success achieved by the ‘Deterrence of Aggression’ campaign. For instance, many armed groups have extensive combat experience across various regions in Syria, including Aleppo and Hama, giving them a deep familiarity with the geography. This experience is further complemented by their history of numerous assaults on regime bases, as well as their involvement in laying sieges. Additionally, sleeper cells played a critical role in supporting the oppositions’ advance, providing intelligence and logistical aid during the operation. Also, the use of drones proved to be a game-changer, giving the opposition a significant advantage by enabling precise strikes on regime troops, tanks, aircraft, helicopters, bases, and even high-ranking commanders.

Jerusalem Post

Rotem Mey-Tal, CEO of Asgard Systems, noted that these rebels are equipped with Western-style weapons and tactics, representing a departure from the Soviet-era equipment typically seen in the region. “The rebels … primarily use Turkish-made weaponry, such as the MPT-76 assault rifle manufactured by Turkey’s military industry (MKEK) and 40mm anti-tank launchers, also produced by MKEK. The rebels move in Western-made Humvees, as Turkey is a NATO member and thus adopts Western techno-military doctrines,” Mey-Tal explained to The Media Line. This contrasts with Assad’s forces, which rely on Soviet-era equipment and Iranian-made missile systems.

They were well led.  The focus on refugee return and promised tolerance and reconciliation (we'll see...) was great marketing to both the locals and the international community desperate to fix their refugee (and captagon) problems.
Apparently, the few times some Syrian army units dug in on the road South to Damascus, the rebel modus operandi was to go around and cut off the road further South - thus isolating them.  Classic, classic, stuff.
Last, it metastasized into a generalized uprising.  Damascus was taken from the South, by other insurgents.  The Syrian Army just had too many fires to put out.
More background, including faction troop numbers and political networks How and why did Assad lose Syria in just 12 days? - YouTube (22 minutes) 

"The rebels move in Western-made Humvees". That's BS alas. I've seen a lot of footage from this war and not a single Humvee. He's confusing them with some home-made armored trucks that look vaguely similar but are not Humvees. They're based on Toyota trucks, I think, with many changes and armor added, in the style of some police or commercial armored cars that move valuables. MEMRI has piece on them, but it's subscribers-only.

@264champagnebottlesonice I don't know, I am not there, I cited the Jerusalem Post, just like I cited a lot of non-US sources here because the locals have been watching Syria a lot more than Western press has over the last few years.  What's your point?  I could easily have commented that your statement "You'll have to wait for some better history of this to be written, especially for the crucial days of 5-7 December" sits at odds with your recent question about HTS support in the south, but I did not bother.  Purely militarily crucial days were Dec 1st-3rd around Hama/Homs, not 3 days later

Here's a photo https://www.straitstimes.com/world/europe/germany-pauses-asylum-applications-for-syrians-after-fall-of-assad A non-expert may think they're "Humvees" It's still quite remarkable that they have dozens of these to lead their columns. But most of the tail is just random pickup trucks with no armor.

Wonderful answer, +1 and added a bounty to reward it.

@JonathanReez Gee, txs :-) I liked OM's answer best of all, but found it long on valid generic military principles and short on Syria specifics.  Plus, I was genuinely curious about what triggered this collapse.  Obvious now that it has happened, but if it hadn't no one would have batted an eye (though maybe they should have).

Multiple factors at the same time
Caveat: The exact reasons are not reliably known. This is a write up of various hints collected from a multiple of articles, and more knowledge might show up at any time, including knowledge that invalidates some of these points.
Still, it's a plausible scenario, and answers how a pretty well-entrenched dictatorial regime can fold as quickly as Assad's did.

Iran's proxies that had been supporting Assad were hit by Israel's attacks, and could not resist a lot.
Likewise, Iran itself was struck by Israel's air strikes, so they were probably not willing to expend forces in Syria, so there was no will to resist.
The Syrian army itself was plagued by corruption and embezzlement. In particular, the air force could not do much because fuel had been sold off on the black market. Such things undermine both the capacity and the will to resist.
Russia did not have the will or capacity to invest a lot of military power into keeping Assad in force. So that's a domino effect: Not enough capacity to resist on its own, and not the will to resist because that would be pointless.
The rebels negotiated non-interference with Turkey. This must have been complicated, as Turkey is loosely associated with the more secular rebel groups but strongly opposed to IS forces. That's possibly the reason why HTS is downplaying its IS roots, or might even have cut its IS connections entirely.
This allowed the rebel forces to confidently attack Assad's forces without having to divert attention and resources to deal with Turkish interference.
They might also have agreements with Turkey for the time when they form a government. This might have been a factor why the rebels were willing to make their move in the first place.
However, this point is purely speculative, I haven't seen any articles reporting on such an agreement or its absence.



How did they manage to do that so quickly?

Some factors:

Al-Assad's regime was missing some of their regular key supports: Russia was busy with Ukraine and Iran was busy with Israel.
Unpopularity of Al-Assad's regime due to economic struggles, past bloody repression, etc.


not my DV, but Iran wasn't busy with Israel, Hezbollah was

@machine_1 Who do you think funds, commands, provides for, and otherwise totally manages Hezbollah?

What you describe here is the situation for several years now. It doesn't answer the question how the scales in this war could tip so quickly in the past couple days.

@Philipp Iran vs. Israel escaladed recently.

@Philipp Surely that part is self-evident: the conditions that allowed the rebels to depose Assad so quickly may well have been present for a while, but only in the last two weeks did they actually decide to make their move. The war had largely gone cold prior to that point. Why the rebels didn't make their move earlier is an entirely separate question.
